# 'multiple definition' and 'undefined reference' errors when linking against an external object file

Tags: g++

I have the following directory structure -

```
YCSB-C/
- db/
  - cceh_store.h (includes <src/CCEH.h>)
  - cceh_store.cc (includes cceh_store.h, <util/hash.h>)
  - cceh_store.o
  - Makefile (1 - builds cceh_store.o)
- ycsb.cc
- Makefile (2 - builds target 'ycsbc' from ycsb.cc by linking it with cceh_store.o)

CCEH/
- src/
  - CCEH.h (defines class CCEH)
  - CCEH_MSB.cc (implements CCEH methods, includes util/hash.h, util/persist.h)
  - CCEH_MSB.o
- util/
  - hash.h
  - persist.h
- Makefile (3 - builds CCEH_MSB.o)
```

1. Makefile (3) is run first to build `CCEH_MSB.o` object file -

`g++ -std=c++17 -I./ -lpthread -O3 -c -o src/CCEH_MSB.o src/CCEH_MSB.cpp -DINPLACE`

2. Then Makefile (1) is run to build `cceh_store.o` object file, which is successful -

`g++-8 -std=c++14 -c -g -Wall -pthread -I../ -I../../CCEH cceh_store.cc -o cceh_store.o`

3. Finally, when I run Makefile (2) to build `ycsbc` -

`g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -pthread -I./ -I../CCEH/ ycsbc.cc db/cceh_store.o ../CCEH/src/CCEH_MSB.o -o ycsbc`

It fails with the following error -

```
../CCEH/src/CCEH_MSB.o: In function `xxhash(void const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)':
CCEH_MSB.cpp:(.text+0x330): multiple definition of `xxhash(void const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
db/cceh_store.o:/home/osboxes/YCSB-C/db/../../CCEH/util/hash.h:236: first defined here

CCEH_MSB.cpp:(.text+0xdea): undefined reference to `kWriteLatencyInNS'
```

Here, `kWriteLatencyInNS` is defined in `CCEH/util/persist.h`

I have spent hours, but I cannot figure out how to get `ycsbc` to build properly. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Please share relevant source files (.cc, .h) that declare, and reference the `kWriteLatencyInNS`. At least, the xxhash function, and the kWriteLatencyInNS declaration in the '.h' and '.cc' files.

Comment: I would say that xxhash is defined (not only declared) in hash.h, so it gets physically put into two object files and that's why it barfs on linking. kWriteLatencyInNS on the other hand is probably nowhere defined; header file only includes declaration but you're missing the object file that actually defines the function.